# Make WP metabox editable only for administrators

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a member directory website and need some help.

I have a taxonomy that is linked to a custom post type in Wordpress. This allows me to apply a geographical region to each post. The problem is that any member how has access to any given post also has access to update the region. I would like to make the region metabox editable only for Administrator roles. Here is the current code:

```
function region() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Regions', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Region', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Regions', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'map_meta_cap'               => false,      
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'region', array( 'installer' ), $args );
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'region', 0 );

I tried changing 'show_ui' to false but that hides it from the admins as well. I know there must be a simple solution, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: What if you make the `show_ui` parameter a boolean variable and at the top of the function do something like `$show_ui = (current_user_can('administrator') ? true : false);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Ty, for pointing me in the right direction. I added an if/else statement that seems to do the trick. See below:

```
function region() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Regions', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Region', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Regions', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
);
if (current_user_can('administrator') ){
    $args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'map_meta_cap'               => false,      
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
}else{
    $args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => false,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'map_meta_cap'               => false,      
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
}
register_taxonomy( 'region', array( 'installer' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'region', 0 );
```

And then I just changed 'show_ui_ from true to false depending on admin vs non-admin roles. If anyone sees an easier way to do this, I would love to see it.